# How do I wait for a class to be added by responsive-tabs before I check which tab is active?

Tags: jquery, onclick

I'm trying to make it so when you click on different tabs on the nav bar, a button will not show up if you are on tab 1, but will show up at all other times.  I'm using responsive-tabs (https://github.com/jellekralt/Responsive-Tabs) .

```
   $('.nav').click(function() {
        if($('#tab-1').hasClass('active'))
        {
            $('#register-now-button').attr('style', 'display:none');
        } else {
            $('#register-now-button').attr('style', 'display:flex');
        }
    });
```

The above code only works on the second time you click.  I realize that hasClass('active') is only true the second time you click on tab 1.  It's checking if tab 1 has the class active before the class gets added.  How do I tell it to wait until after the active class has been added to switch out the attributes?  The class "active" is being added by the responsive-tabs.

Comment: please provide full code (html,css,js)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by wrapping it in a check function with a timeout!

```
    $('.nav').click(function() {
        var check = function() {
            if($('#tab-1').hasClass('active'))
            {
                $('#register-now-button').attr('style', 'display:none');
            } else {
                $('#register-now-button').attr('style', 'display:flex');
            }
        }
        setTimeout(check, 200);
    });
```